# Water damaged mid 2014 Macbook Pro - SSD question

Tags: macbook-pro, ssd

My laptop got wet in my bag, and I want to try to retrieve the data from the hard drive. My old Mac computers used SATA II drives, and I have a cable that can plug right in.

Is there something similar for this generation Mac? If the SSD isn't damaged, I have some important things on there I need.

The model is a MacBook Pro (Retina, 15-inch, Mid 2014).

Comment: When you get a new computer up and running, please consider making backups of your files for exactly this sort of eventuality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is.  OWC makes a [USB3 to PCIe Enclosure](http://radnex.us/OWC_SSD_Enclosure_2013-2015) that will allow you to hook your drive up to a USB port so you can mount the drive and copy over your data.  These are a bit pricey (thanks to Apple's *proprietary* PCIe interface), but even the cheaper no-name ones are only a few dollars less - go with a trusted brand like OWC.

Another option, is where ever you take your MacBook to get repaired, they should be able to offer this service to you for free or even for a nominal fee.  [Rossman Repair Group](https://rossmanngroup.com/) has the ability to save your data even if it's one of the SSDs that are soldered to the logic board.  (I'm not affiliated; just a very happy customer).